# Can you initiate a phone call by sending an SMS message using twilio?

Tags: twilio

As the title states what I would like to do is be able to text a number and have that number initiate a phone call.

is this possible with Twilios API?

Answer (score 5):

yes; Twilio will make a request to the SMS url that you specify when it receives a SMS.  You can initiate the phone call in the logic on the page that the SMS url points to.

check out http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You configure an SMS endpoint for your application / telephone number. When someone SMS's that number, Twilio will request the endpoint and the logic you have on that page can initiate a Telephone Call.